# Inserting a text box with a field (file name)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working with word, Office 2010 and I have this macro that inserts a text box with the text "ABC".

```
Sub AddATextBox()
 Dim Box As Shape
 Set Box = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
 Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
 Left:=20, Top:=780, Width:=100, Height:=100)

 With Box
 .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "ABC"
 .Line.Visible = msoFalse
 Box.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
 Box.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 6
 End With
 End Sub
```

Instead of the text "ABC", I would like this macro to insert into the text box the field "file name". Preferably without the file extension, but if it's complicated then I can live with it.

How can it be done? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code below will insert a textbox at the bottom of the page and write the active document's name into it. Note that the shape isn't part of the footer. It is anchored in the main document body.

```
Sub InsertATextBox()

    Dim Box As Shape
    Dim Sp() As String

    Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name

    Set Box = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
                             Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                             Left:=20, Top:=780, Width:=120, Height:=12)

    Sp = Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")
    ReDim Preserve Sp(UBound(Sp) - 1)

    With Box
        With .TextFrame.TextRange
            .Text = Join(Sp, ".")
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Font.Size = 6
        End With
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
    End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!

Comment: I am delighted to learn that my suggestion helped you. Please mark the answer as "accepted" so that this thread is visibly, and successfully, closed.